# Why is this html program gives an output like this?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<h3>This is heading 3</h3>
<h4>This is heading 4</h4>
<h5>This is heading 5</h5>
<h6>This is heading 6</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run this programme then the desired o/p will come but my question is why the o/p is like that since i've not included break or textsize command.And one more thing if you try to add one more heading then it comes in regular size also from that statement the previous order doesn't follow anymore,WHY IS THAT ??

Comment: You need to read up on what HTML is and how it works. These are some very basic questions that would be covered by any introductory information on HTML. And don't call it a ‘program’ or say that you ‘run’ it: HTML is a *markup* language.

Comment: First of all, that is not a “programme”. HTML is not a programming language. And secondly, browsers have a user agent stylesheet that contains default formatings to apply for certain HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, i just started HTML couple of days ago since you could know from my profile this is my first question here.Sorry if my question got unclear or not specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the o/p is like that since i've not included break or textsize command

HTML describes the semantics of content. Elements designed to describe presentation are, in general, obsolete or remain only for historical reasons.

It is the job of the browser to present those semantics to the user with whatever visual metaphors the authors of the browser consider appropriate (such showing headings on a line of their own, in a larger font size and in bold and/or italic and the specifics changing and you move from level 1 headings to level 2 sub-headings and so on).  For the most part this is relatively consistent across browsers.

(Presentation will be noticeably different when the user is viewing the page on a braille display, using a screen readers, or a terminal emulator).

Most browsers support CSS which allows a page author to provide custom styling for a page. The browser's default presentation is usually implemented as an internal CSS file.

> if you try to add one more heading then it comes in regular size

Assuming you mean `<h7>`, that is because [there is no `h7` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements) defined in HTML so the browser attempts error recovery (using a standard mechanism that it uses for all unrecognised elements).

Answer (score 1):

`h1` through `h6` doesn't mean heading number 1 through 6. It means level 1 through 6. `h1` is a main title, `h2` is a sub-title, `h3` is a sub-sub-title, and so on.

Each article should have a single `h1`, each section a single `h2`, and further subdivisions use `h3` through `h6`.